# Add strip_tags exceptions in smarty

Tags: smarty

I am trying to add strip_tags exceptions for smarty but for some reason it is not working. below is my code. can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
<td class="olotd4 tooltip2">
<span>{$customer_work_orders_result
[i].WORK_ORDER_DESCRIPTION|strip_tags:"<a><del><em><strong><blockquote>"|stripslashes}</span>
{$customer_work_orders_result[i].WORK_ORDER_SCOPE}</td>
```

it is working but stripping everything.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smarty strip_tags implementation does not allow that. You can, however, write your own modifier:

save it as smarty/plugins/modifier.strip_tags_exclude.php (or in your custom plugins folder)

```
function smarty_modifier_strip_tags_exclude()
{

    $params=func_get_args();

    if (!isset($params[1])) {
        $params[1] = true;
    }
    if ($params[1] === true) {
        return preg_replace('!<[^>]*?>!', ' ', $params[0]);
    } else {
        if (is_string($params[1]))
        {
            $allowable_tags = strtr($params[1],'[]','<>');
        }


        return strip_tags($params[0],$allowable_tags);
    }
}
```

and then you can use it this way:

```
{$variable|strip_tags_exclude:'<a><p><ul><li>'}
```

or alternatively (some editors may get confused and think that you're opening tags):

```
{$variable|strip_tags_exclude:'[a][p][ul][li]'}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I've also found some docs on the smarty website. thanks once again.